# bind ng-click to a css class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Can we bind ng-click to a CSS class?

I have loads of `<td>`s to bind and check if they are clicked then fire the click of the label in it, in order to give a maximum clickable area for touch devices.

I have done something like below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", ["$scope", "$timeout", function myController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.checkRadio = function checkRadio($event) {      
      $timeout(function() {
        angular.element($event.target).find("label").trigger('click');
      }, 100);
    };
  }]);
```

```css
.invisible-radio {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-radio-label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
}

.custom-radio-label::before {
  border-color: #7f7f7f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-width: 2px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.invisible-radio:checked+.custom-radio-label::after {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover text-center center-block" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Option 1</th>
      <th>Option 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-click="checkRadio($event)">
        <input id="option1" type="radio" class="invisible-radio" name="option" value="0" ng-model="model.Option" required />
        <label class="custom-radio-label" for="option1"></label>
      </td>
      <td ng-click="checkRadio($event)">
        <input id="option2" type="radio" class="invisible-radio" name="option" value="1" ng-model="model.Option" required />
        <label class="custom-radio-label" for="option2"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But it seems overkill to go and decorate 100s of `<td>`s with `ng-click` attribute.

I am thinking if it is possible to bind `ng-click` to a common class that all my `<td>`s share.

It is certainly possible to do it with `jQuery` as below.

```
$(".someclassOnMyTD").click($event) {
   $event.target.find("label").click();
}
```

But I am looking for an Angular way here. A directive possibly.

Comment: Are those 100 `td`'s not generated in any way using a loop?

Comment: @Icycool, nope! That's the tragedy! :( Otherwise, this question would not have existed. :) So I am going to try Mr_Perfect's answer if it works. As yours is an excellent suggestion, however, it will require me updating HTML for all those `td`s.

Comment: well you would have to do that for directive as well, like `<td click-me>`. imo using jquery in angular when necessary is fine.

Comment: Totally agree there with you @Icycool! I think using the best features of both jQuery and AngularJs is perfectly fine in situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

```
  var cells = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".someclassOnMyTD"));
  cells.on('click', function(event){
        // write your code here
        // var labels = angular.element(event.currentTarget).find('label');
  })
```

Comment: I went on to use your solution and built my requirement on top of it. Certainly gave me a start!

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is what a `<label>` for.

```
<td>
  <label for="option1">
    <input id="option1" type="radio" class="invisible-radio" name="option" value="0" ng-model="model.Option" required />
    <label class="custom-radio-label" for="option1"></label>
  </label>
</td>
```

You might need to tinker with the CSS a little so it fills the area of its parent `td`

Answer (score 0):

I was using `ng-view` and needed to bind the event to a lot of `td`s in almost all of my (more than 20) views.

Here's complete solution as it might turn useful to someone with the similar requirement as mine, in future.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    var tables = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".myClassOnTable, .myOtherClassOnTable"));
    angular.forEach(tables, function (table) {
        angular.element(table).on("click", function (e) {
            var targetElement = e.target;
            if (targetElement.nodeName == "TD" || targetElement.nodeName == "td") {
                var radio = angular.element(targetElement).find(".invisible-radio");
                if (radio) {
                    angular.element(radio[0]).prop("checked", true);
                    // I needed to set the required attribute manually as I am setting the checked property manually
                    $scope.myForm[radio[0].name].$setValidity("required", true);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Notice that I have tied the click event to the `table` element and I am listening if the target of the click is a `td`. This is because I was running into below error due to a browser limitation to bind click events to hundreads of elements at the same time.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

So I am delegating the click event to a lesser number of elements.